# Traditional Microsoft Games (Minesweeper, Freecell, Solitaire) in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, windows-8-games

I loved playing Minesweeper in my spare time on Windows 7. I can't find it on Windows 8. What happened to Minesweeper and other Microsoft Games (Chess, Solitaire)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From the Start Screen

- Click on the "Store" app tile
- Click on "Top Free" selection 
  [image]
- Scroll along until you find Microsoft Solitaire Collection and Microsoft Minesweeper
  [image]
- Install them
- Play them

Then go back and check out a few of the others. The free Microsoft Mahjong is very colourful

Comment: Crikey. My text only post has turned into a full multimedia experience in less than 30 minutes :-)

Comment: But the games are huge in size!!

Answer (score 2):

Chess Titans is gone. People have been able to copy it over though.

Below are the available games that have come with Windows is the past.

### [Microsoft Solitaire Collection](http://apps.microsoft.com/webpdp/app/1a36fd17-5161-4651-ae2d-13384e427ea8)

- Solitaire
- FreeCell (Windows 95)
- Spider (Windows ME)
- TriPeaks (Microsoft Windows Entertainment Pack)

### [Microsoft Minesweeper](http://apps.microsoft.com/webpdp/app/45ac18d7-e742-494f-a1b1-009aa412a179)

Circa Windows 3

### [Pinball FX2](http://apps.microsoft.com/webpdp/app/cb9608e7-ac6b-4127-85b7-f81e27c9ebf0)

Preceeded by [3D Pinball for Windows - Space Cadet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_Tilt!_Pinball#3D_Pinball_for_Windows_-_Space_Cadet)? (Microsoft Plus! 95)

### [Microsoft Mahjong](http://apps.microsoft.com/webpdp/app/8f3ca3ad-75bc-4492-8c08-a059360e9609)

Was in the Microsoft Windows Entertainment Pack, came back as Mahjong Titans in Vista.

Comment: Bring back Reversi from Windows 1.0... :P

Answer (score 2):

They are gone.

You can see the instructions on how ot get them from a previous version of Windows here: http://www.intowindows.com/play-windows-7-games-in-windows-8/